# Using "case" with awk

Tags: awk

Some time ago, I used this part of my awk script:

```
case "AlarmLevel.0" :
      alarmAlertLevel=$2
    break
```

But now, the version of information has changed, and the level is dynamic, I mean now, the last number of level can change, it could be 2, 3 or any another number.

I tried put at the end some like this:

```
case "AlarmLevel\\.[0-9]+" :
      alarmAlertLevel=$2
    break
```

But it doesn't work.

**Q:** Does some one have any suggestions?

Comment: jasonwryan, a literal dot has to be escaped in a regexp, as to not match any character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A switch/case statement is a non-standard extension. If you use GNU awk the syntax for your application case is

```
case /AlarmLevel\.[0-9]+/ :
```